# Apply function parameters from a package to a matrix

Tags: r

I am following the these two vignettes for a new package "Time series representations" or TSrepr:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSrepr/vignettes/TSrepr_representations_use_case.html

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSrepr/vignettes/TSrepr_representations_of_time_series.html

In the second tutorial I can do the following:

```
data("elec_load")

data_ts <- as.numeric(elec_load[1,])

data_dwt <- repr_dwt(data_ts, level = 3)
```

However I have a matrix of many values therefore I would like to pass arguments to the function `repr_dwt` such as `level = 3`

Data: - code which works but cannot add arguments:

```
library(TSrepr)

data("elec_load")

data_ts <- elec_load

data_dwt <- repr_matrix(as.matrix(data_ts), func = repr_dwt)
```

Here I pass a matrix argument.

How can I do the "following"

```
 data_dwt <- repr_matrix(as.matrix(data_ts), func = repr_dwt(level = 3))
```

I have a matrix and not a data frame.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create an [anonymous function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/function.html) using the `function()` command.
I could not load the package you use, but given that your general syntax is correct, I would suggest the following:

```
data_dwt <- repr_matrix(as.matrix(data_ts), func = function(x){repr_dwt(x, level = 3)})
```

This gives in your call to `repr_matrix`, for your argument `fun =` an anonymous function (one that has no name, so it does not show up in your environment) of `x` which puts `x`in `repr_dwt` with the hardcoded argument `level = 3`.